# JSP EL not recognizing Java variable

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP, I have the following set, which is supposed to create a table row for each row in my database:

```
<% 
    int count = Controller.getRowCount();for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {%>
    <tr class = resultRow>
        <td><input type=text name='ID<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[0]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Player<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[1]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Character<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[2]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Strength<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[3]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Constitution<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[4]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Dexterity<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[5]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Intelligence<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[6]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Wisdom<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[7]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Charisma<%= i %>' form ='currentCharacter' value='${requestScope.resultRow[8]}'></td>
        <td><button onclick = 'ShowInventory(<%= i %>)'>Inventory</button></td>
        <td><input type=submit form = 'currentCharacter' value=Update name='Update<%= i %>'></td>
        <td><input type=submit form = 'currentCharacter' value=Delete name='Delete<%= i %>'></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

In my EL, I'm trying to get the same effect as `${requestScope.resultRow[0+(9*i)]}`, however, `i` is not read by my EL at all. How can I reference `i` in this situation? Currently, the first row is repeated 4 times in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference `i` in this situation, the trick is to add `request.setAttribute("i", i);` before the `<tr>` defenition.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could put the variable in the pageContext to make it local to this JSP:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("i", i);
```